# How to create a .txt file on Android KitKat and send it with an email intent

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-4.4-kitkat

So i've been trying for a day now to create a .txt file on the SD card only to find out it wasnt my code that was wrong but KitKat no longer allows devs to store files on the external SD card; is there away around this such as a temporary .txt file, or some new code to create a file then send it? 
this is my current code that doesnt work

```
 String DataIn = PhoneNumber + "," + dataLong + "," + dataLat;
        try
        {
        File storageDirectory = new File ("/sdcard/LocationData.txt");
            storageDirectory.createNewFile();
            FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(storageDirectory);
            OutputStreamWriter myoutwriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fout);
            myoutwriter.append(DataIn);
            myoutwriter.close();Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        Intent emailintent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        emailintent.setType("text/plain");
        emailintent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"xxxxxxxx@xxxxxxxxx.com"});
        emailintent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Data");
        emailintent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hello World!");
        File root = Environment.getRootDirectory();
        String DataAttachment = "/sdcard/LocationData.txt";
        File filer = new File(root, DataAttachment);
        if (!filer.exists() || filer.canRead())
        {
            return;
        }
        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(filer);
        emailintent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailintent, "Choose an Email provider"));
```

Comment: you should never use static paths like /sdcard. Instead use getExternalStorageDirectory and make your folder. and then inside it write your file.

Comment: Kitkat still allows apps to write files on removable media. But only in app specific folders like "/storage/1/Android/data/data/<packagename>/files". You can find out your paths with `getExternalFileDirs()`. It should be one of them.

Comment: even if i do that it wont work, kitkat just wont let me write to an external directory

Comment: @greenapps can you give me an example please?

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: Just google for getExternalFileDirs and choose the stackoverflow links.

Comment: @Fildor there is no error message

Comment: @greenapps can you please link and example, i cant find one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        File dirs[] = ContextCompat.getExternalFilesDirs(getApplicationContext(),null);

        String Info = "getExternalFilesDirs()\ndirs.length: " + dirs.length;
        int nr = -1;            
        while ( ++nr < dirs.length )
            Info += "\n"+  dirs[nr].getAbsolutePath();

        Toast.makeText(this, Info, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

You need /Project/libs/android-support-v4.jar file.

Comment: i get a message /storage/emulated.... when i run this on a real device and when i check the card a file is not created

Comment: can i get the jar file from the sdk manager or do i have to find it online

Comment: You can find it online.

Answer (score 0):

i used this code to create .txt file on external storage and its working fine on all versions

```
 File rootPath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), DNAME);
    if(!rootPath.exists()) {
        rootPath.mkdirs();
    }
    File dataFile = new File(rootPath, FILENAME);
    if(!Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Cannot use storage.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();
        return;
    }
    try {           
        FileOutputStream mOutput = new FileOutputStream(dataFile, false);
        String data = "DATA";
        mOutput.write(data.getBytes());
        mOutput.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Yes that will work on all versions but it will not create a file on removable media like a micro sd card. Instead it will create a file in external memory.

Comment: for SD card use this `File myFile = new File("/sdcard/mysdfile.txt");
   myFile.createNewFile();`

Comment: but its recomended not to hardcode path so i used my above code

Answer (score 0):

for me following solution worked.
to create a text file use this

```
    File root = new File(DIRECTORY_PATH);
    File gpxfile = new File(root, "samples.txt");
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(gpxfile);
    writer.append("First string is here to be written.");
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
```

for email

```
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { "email" });
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "test " +    "Subject");
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "test body");
    shareIntent.setType("application/octet-stream");
            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,Uri.parse("file://"+DIRECTORY_PATH+"/samples.txt"));
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Choose service"),EMAIL_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello use this method to store file in SD Card:

```
 public void generateNoteOnSD(String sFileName, String sBody) {
    try {
        File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "hChat");
        if (!root.exists()) {
            root.mkdirs();
        }
        File gpxfile = new File(root, sFileName);
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(gpxfile);
        writer.append(sBody);
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        Toast.makeText(context, "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and for send this file with intent then use these LOC

```
** File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File fileDir= new File(sd, "dir_path");
            Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(fileDir.getAbsolutePath() + "/"
                            + "hchatDB.txt"));
                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email , "Email: Text File"));**
```